# Some fields I have deleted in the past still show up in translation strings, how to get rid of them?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

Some old fields that I deleted still show up in translation strings, so they are still somewhere in the database, but they don't show up under fields list.

I saw an article over here on function field_purge_batch :

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_purge_batch/7

Is that what I need to do?

Where do I put the code:

```
function field_purge_batch

7 field.crud.inc    field_purge_batch($batch_size)
```

Is there a module for this, do I have to change code?